# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, fade

I am getting : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined
at animateIfInview
at atonscroll

and heres the code :

```
 <script>
 function animateIfInView() {
 $.each($("content-img"), function(key, value) {
 if (isElementInViewport($(value))) {
 $(value).addClass("content-img-in-view");
 } else {
  // (Optional) Fade out when out of view
  $(value).removeClass("content-img-in-view");
  }
  });
  }

  // http://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/5628
   function isElementInViewport(el) {
    //special bonus for those using jQuery
  if (typeof jQuery === "function" && el instanceof jQuery) {
  el = el[0];
  }

  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

  return (
  rect.top >= 0 &&
  rect.left >= 0 &&
  rect.bottom <=
  (window.innerHeight ||
  document.documentElement.clientHeight) /*or $(window).height() */ &&
  rect.right <=
  (window.innerWidth ||
  document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
  );
  }
  </script>
```

How can I fix this error? what am I missing in code? Thanks guys in advance

Comment: This: `$("content-img")` is an incorrect selector. Is this for a ID or a Class?

Comment: I would also suggest using `$(".content-img").each();`

Comment: its for a class,so every image on that page do same fade in on scroll thing

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
function animateIfInView() {
  $(".content-img").each(function(key, elem) {
    if (isElementInViewport($(elem))) {
      $(elem).toggleClass("content-img-in-view");
    }
  });
}
```

The class selector uses `$(".className")`, where your code is missing the `.` in it. Also, if using elements, it is suggested to use `.each()` versus `$.each()` which is suggests for Arrays and Objects.

Comment: Thank you much,I will try it out when I get on work pc,will let you know and vote you if it works

Comment: For some reason nothing changes :( dont know why

Comment: Your code should work, as long as you use the right selector: `.content-img`

Comment: can you pls check the page here : http://fracturize.me/work/snaaak-2-11/       ,maybe you can see what is wrong,thanks in advance man

Comment: @nellement I found two syntax errors right away that will need to be addressed. SyntaxError: missing ; before statement  snaaak-2-11:474:37 & SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' snaaak-2-11:917

Comment: Can you sharescreenshot of that error pls,so I can find it in html and fix,Im sorry for bugging you like this,but I'm really coding noob,trying to make stuff work somehow

Comment: Ok found the error console,just need to find it in code and try fix,thanks man hope it works out

Comment: Just tried fixing all thats in red error,but it doesnt work for some reason and it kiling me becasue no clue why

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.each(array/object,callback_function);
```

require first parameter as an array or an object. Read documentation 
[here](http://api.jquery.com/JQuery.each/) . I suggest to use `var obj = $(document).find(".content-img");` then use
as

```
$.each(obj,function(key,value){
//your code goes here
});
```

Comment: Can you tell me more what code to ad on top of mine in original post to make this work? Thanks in advance